# Rails: dynamically define class method based on parent class name within module/concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, metaprogramming, mixins

I want to dynamically generate a class method in a Mixin, based on the class name that include this Mixin.

Here is my current code:

```
module MyModule  
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern  

  # def some_methods  
  #   ...  
  # end  

  module ClassMethods  

    # Here is where I'm stuck...
    define_method "#{self.name.downcase}_status" do  
      # do something...  
    end  

  end  
end  

class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base  
  include MyModule  
end  

# What I'm trying to achieve:
MyClass.myclass_status
```

But this give me the following method name:

```
MyClass.mymodule::classmethods_status
```

Getting the base class name inside the method definition works (self, self.name...) but I can't make it works for the method name...

So far, I've tried

```
define_method "#{self}"
define_method "#{self.name"
define_method "#{self.class}"
define_method "#{self.class.name}"
define_method "#{self.model_name}"
define_method "#{self.parent.name}"
```

But none of this seems to do the trick :/

Is there any way I can retrieve the base class name (not sure what to call the class that include my module). I've been struggling with this problem for hours now and I can't seem to figure out a clean solution :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do it like that - at this point it is not yet known which class (or classes) are including the module.

If you define a `self.included` method it will be called each time the module is included and the thing doing the including will be passed as an argument. Alternatively since you are using AS::Concern you can do

```
included do 
  #code here is executed in the context of the including class
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I used `define_singleton_method` inside the `included do #... end` block:   `define_singleton_method "#{self.name}_status" do #... end`
`

Answer (score 8):

I found a clean solution: using `define_singleton_method` (available in ruby v1.9.3)

```
module MyModule  
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern  

  included do
    define_singleton_method "#{self.name}_status" do
      # do stuff
    end
  end

  # def some_methods  
  #   ...  
  # end  

  module ClassMethods  
    # Not needed anymore!
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
module MyModule
  def self.included(base)
    (class << base; self; end).send(:define_method, "#{base.name.downcase}_status") do
      puts "Hey!"
  end

  base.extend(ClassMethods)
end

  module ClassMethods
    def other_method
      puts "Hi!"
    end
  end
end

class MyClass
  include MyModule
end

MyClass.myclass_status
MyClass.other_method
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for `extend`:

```
module MyModule  
  def self.extended who
    define_method "#{who.name.downcase}_status" do
      p "Inside"
    end
  end
end  

class MyClass  
  extend MyModule  
end  

MyClass.myclass_status
```